# Cant see user data permission for facebook user_friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get facebook friends in my app and i have added some testers for it so that i don't have to send my app for review for now.

I am not getting an option for selecting the user_friends checkbox from the graph API Explorer.

this is the image..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFSF1.jpg

I want the user_friends Permission in the list.

Is it from my side or the facebook issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app seems to be in “live” mode.

Newer apps need to be set into development mode, for that dialog in Graph API Explorer to show all available permissions; otherwise you are limited to a few default ones and already reviewed ones.

So, but your app in dev mode, to be able to develop and test your feature.